# How to access an SQLite database under the Android app sandbox storage?

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a native app which generates an SQLite database file in the com.companyname.appname/databases/MyDatabase.db. This is in the internal app storage of Android.

I need to migrate this app into Xamarin.Forms but I need to access that database either to move it to another directory or read the database directly.

The problem is that using the `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` / `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` which is the highest possible location as said in the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/) only results in the com.companyname.appname/files/ location. I need to go one level higher to access the database folder. Is this possible?

Note: I have tried hardcoding the path, and also adding "../" which doesn't work and throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that using the System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal / System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments which is the highest possible location as said in the documentation here only results in the com.companyname.appname/files/ location.

The `Personal directory` that serves as a common repository for documents is equivalent to `MyDocuments`. For more information, you could check the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8

A simple way to read database with Personal folder.

```
string databaseFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                string databasePath = Path.Combine(docFolder, "TodoSQLite2.db3");
```

Copy the exited database to **Assets** folder.

[image]

And set the **Build Action** to **AndroidAsset**.

[image]

**Updated:**

If you want to copy the database to another folder at runtime, you could try the code below. I use local folder for example.

```
// Check if it exists at that path
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
   // Copy the file to the app's local folder, you could change the path where you want to copy.
   string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
   string destinationPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "myData.db");
   File.Copy(filePath, destinationPath);
}
```

Comment: How do I programatically get the folder above the 'System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal' then? In Xamarin.Android I only get the com.companyname.appname/files/ location.

Comment: @iamlawrencev What is the "get the folder above the 'System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal' then" mean?  Do you mean you want to set the folder which used to save the dadabase programmatically? If yes, you could try the code `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "TodoSQLite.db3")` to set the path.

Comment: I meant to programatically navigate to the folder above the folder returned by the System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal code. I need to copy the database to another folder at runtime.

Comment: @iamlawrencev I have updated my reply, please check the updated code.

Comment: this still doesn't solve the initial problem wherein I cannot access the com.companyname.appname/databases/MyDatabase.db location since the Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal only goes to the com.companyname.appname/files location. If I can access the folder one level up from that location and navigate to the databases folder then it would be trivial to copy.

Comment: What is the error? Have you set the runtime permission?